# Example of strongly continuous group of operators

Tags: operator-theory

I have to check if the collection of operators $\{ A(t)\}_{t \in R}$ is a strongly continuous unitary group, where:

$$A(t):L^2(R)\rightarrow L^2(R)$$ 
$$(A(t)\psi)(x)=e^\frac t 2 \psi(e^tx)$$
I've already checked that:

1)  $\forall t \in R : $ $A(t)$ is a unitary operator;

2) $A(0)=\mathbb{I }$

3) $A(t+s)=A(t)A(s)$

I still have to show that the collection of operator is strongly continuous:

4) $ \forall \psi \in L^2(R): \quad A(t)\psi \rightarrow \psi \quad$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider applying [Stone's theorem on one-parameter unitary groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone's_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups) which establishes a one-to-one connection between strongly continuous unitary groups and a generator, i.e. a (possibly unbounded) operator $H$ acting on some dense domain $D(L^2(\mathbb R))\subset L^2(\mathbb R))$ such that $$A(t)=e^{itH}$$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

It turns out that your "collection of operators" $\lbrace A(t)\rbrace_{t\in\mathbb R}$ simply is the squeezing operator generated by $$H_A=\frac12 (\hat x\hat p+\hat p\hat x)\,,$$ refer to, e.g., [Section IV & VIII in this article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1599074) (click [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0301024) for the arXiv version). This $H_A$ involves the [position operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_operator)
$$
\hat x: D(\hat x) \to L^2(\mathbb R) \qquad \psi(x)\mapsto x\psi(x)
$$
and the [momentum operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator) (set $\hbar=1$)
$$
\hat p: D(\hat p) \to L^2(\mathbb R) \qquad \psi(x)\mapsto -i\psi'(x)
$$
on appropriate domains $$\mathcal S(\mathbb R)\subset D(H_A)\subset D(\hat x)\cap D(\hat p)\subset L^2(\mathbb R)$$ which contain the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) and are chosen such that $\hat x,\hat p,H_A$ are self-adjoint. Then one readily verifies that
$$
e^{itH_A}\psi(x)=e^{t/2}e^{tx\frac{d}{dx}}\psi(x)=e^{t/2}\psi(e^tx)=(A(t)\psi)(x)
$$
for all $t\in\mathbb R$ which in turn by Stone's theorem implies strong continuity of the unitary group in question.